# How to set Mainpage as permanent after Login in xamarin forms?

Tags: c#, authentication, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I want to Set my main page as permanent after Login

i dont know how to set this

this is the splash screen pure cs code:

```
protected override async void OnAppearing()
{
    base.OnAppearing();
    await splashImage.FadeTo(0, 1000);
    await splashImage.FadeTo(1, 1000);
    await splashImage.FadeTo(0, 1000);
    await splashImage.FadeTo(1, 1000);
    await sub.RelRotateTo(360, 1000, Easing.BounceOut);
    Application.Current.MainPage = new Homemaster();
}
```

this is my App

```cs
public App(){
    InitializeComponent();
    MainPage = new Login();
}
```

and my Login page to push main page

```cs
using System;
using System.IO;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace sing
{
    public partial class Login : ContentPage
    {
        public Login()
        {
            NavigationPage.SetHasNavigationBar(this, false);
            var SignUp = new NavigationPage(new SignUp());
            var Homepage = new NavigationPage(new View1());
            Application.Current.MainPage = new  Homepage();
            InitializeComponent();
        }
```

this is the continuation of the code above
try to look the NavigationPage my target is Homepage()

```
        private async void ButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
         
         overlay.IsVisible = true;
         TimeSpan duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3);
          DateTime startTime = DateTime.Now;
          Device.StartTimer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0), () =>
         {
            double progress = (DateTime.Now - startTime).TotalMilliseconds /duration.TotalMilliseconds;
            progressBar.Progress = progress;
            bool continueTimer = progress < 1;
            if (!continueTimer)
            {
                overlay.IsVisible = false;
                DisplayAlert("Account", "Login Successful", "Done");
                Navigation.PushAsync(new Homepage());
            }
            return continueTimer;
         });
        }
        private async void Button2(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            bool answer = await DisplayAlert("Question", "Do you want to continue?" , "Yes" , "No");
            Console.WriteLine("Answer:" + answer);
            if(answer is true)
            {
                await Navigation.PushAsync(new SignUp());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Change your MainPage to it - `Application.Current.MainPage = new HomePage()`

Comment: how can i Call the Login() class in App class

Comment: You don't need to call your Login in your App. In your login page, when you've finished with the login flow, simply copy-paste the code. It's swapping the application's `MainPage` to the `HomePage`.

Comment: @Newbietots Hi , have you solved this ? If so , remember to update this as an answer when you have time :-)

Comment: its still not working

Comment: @Newbietots Okey , share your code in `Login` page how to navigate to `MainPage` . And explain where not works now .

Comment: @Junior Jiang check my update code above

Comment: i just wanted to make my HomePage as main page ... if I  logging in to login form and display the HomePage ...then after closing the app if i launch again the app the HomePage will display permanently

Comment: @Newbietots If next time opening app to show `HomePage` automatically , you need to check when launching . I will update answer .

Comment: @Newbietots I have updated answer . You can save the `loginStatus` flag in local to determine whether need to navigate to Login Page next lauching app .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From shared scene , we will set the `MainPage` as the **Root Page** in `App.xaml.cs` :

```
public App()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    MainPage = new NavigationPage(new MainPage());
}
```

When first launching the app , will enter the `MainPage` to determine whether need to log in .

```
public MainPage()
{      
    InitializeComponent();
    
    var LoginPage = new NavigationPage(new Login());
    
    var loginStatus = Preferences.Get("loginStatus", "0");
    if(loginStatus == 0)
    {
        Application.Current.MainPage = LoginPage;
    }else{
      // do nothing
    }

}
```

In Login Page , remove  `Application.Current.MainPage` in the constructor method :

```
public Login()
{      
    InitializeComponent();

    NavigationPage.SetHasNavigationBar(this, false);
    var SignUp = new NavigationPage(new SignUp());
    var Homepage = new NavigationPage(new View1());
}
```

Then in Button click method modified as follow :

```
private async void ButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    overlay.IsVisible = true;
    TimeSpan duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3);
    DateTime startTime = DateTime.Now;
    Device.StartTimer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0), () =>
    {
        double progress = (DateTime.Now - startTime).TotalMilliseconds /duration.TotalMilliseconds;
        progressBar.Progress = progress;
        bool continueTimer = progress < 1;
        if (!continueTimer)
        {
            overlay.IsVisible = false;
            DisplayAlert("Account", "Login Successful", "Done");
            //Navigation.PushAsync(new Homepage());
            
            Preferences.Set("loginStatus", "1");
            // save loginStatus value
            Application.Current.MainPage = Homepage;
        }
        return continueTimer;
     });
}
```

Then next time lauching appp will not naivgate to Login Page .

Comment: its working man but may i ask if there is a Splashscreen -> login form -> main home page

Comment: after loging in successful ..close the app then it will load the Splash screen -> home main page in  next launching the app then the login form will not display??

Comment: is it possible to do that in xamarin forms?

Comment: Jiang  can you help me about the splash screen i make a Splashscreen before Login form and im using pure cs  code no Xaml

Comment: @Newbietots About splash screen , have a look at this : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/splashscreen#xamarinforms-ios-splash-screen